# how can I consider $(this)?

Tags: jquery, this

Hello I have a doubt about `$(this)` in jQuery. I was doing an exercise, at the end of the script you can see:

```
$(this).before(quote);
```

Can I consider `$(this)` as temporary variable that contains the value of that loop? In generally how can I consider `$(this)`?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('span.pq').each(function() {
    var quote = $(this).clone();
    quote.removeClass('pq');
    quote.addClass('pullquote');
    $(this).before(quote);
  }); //end each
}); // end ready
```

Comment: `this` = the `span.pq` Element. `$(this)` = the `span.pq` element wrapped in a jQuery object so you can call jQuery methods on that element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('span.pq')` will return you the list of elements which is basically an array of elements. `$(this)` will be element of `$('span.pq')` array of elements.

$(this) will be equal to $('span.pq')[index] // say index is an variable of each loop.

Comment: OK I understand you.
Now after using .clone() in the var quote I will have the original string plus its copy, right?
But with removeClass it will remove .pq to both??
The problem is that when I use source page in the browser the html code is the same, so I am not sure how it works.
THanks